# How to update only the month and year values of a date?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have a static date 28-04-2012,. I want to update the only the month when the date gets to the 28th of the new month. So if the date is `28-05-2012`, then `28-06-2012`, `28-07-2012` and so on.

I would also like to update the year when I reach 2013. But always keep the date at 28?  Can someone advise me how this would be done using js or php?

Comment: Did you work anything on it??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$current_date = "28-04-2012";
$next_month = strtotime($current_date . "+1month");

echo date('Y-m-d', $next_month);
```

the most simple trick i guess.

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
$date = '28-04-2012';

echo date('j-m-Y', strtotime("1 month", strtotime($date))) . "\n";
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

See here: http://www.roseindia.net/tutorial/php/phpdate/php-date-add-1-month.html

```
$todayDate = date("Y-m-d");// current date
echo "Today: ".$todayDate."<br>";

//Add one day to today
$dateOneMonthAdded = strtotime(date("Y-m-d", strtotime($todayDate)) . "+1 month");

echo "After adding one month: ".date('l dS \o\f F Y', $dateOneMonthAdded)."<br>";
```

Answer (score 0):

People are suggesting `strtotime()`, but I have to say I have a strong dislike for this function. It isn't designed for date arithmetic, but it was the only option available in older versions of PHP, so everyone uses it for that.

A better solution can be found in the PHP5 [`DateTime` class](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php), and in particular the [`DateTime::Add`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php) method (also known as the `date_add()` function).

The only reason to use `strtotime() instead of`DateTime::Add()`is if you're using a version of PHP older than 5.3, since this is when the`Add` method was added. But if that's the case, your first priority should be to upgrade your PHP.